# How to combine conditions with xdotool?

Tags: xdotool

Is it possible to search for both the `--class` and `--name` using xdotool?

```
xdotool search --all --onlyvisible --class "some_val" --name "another val"
```

The above returns an error because the first condition, `--class`, already returns window ids before `--name` can be used to filter the results:

```
 xdotool: Unknown command: --name
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tricky thing is that --class, --name, and --classname options to the search command **do not take an argument**.  (This has tripped many, I think.)  They modify what the search command looks at.

Chaining searches doesn't work, either; the second search discards the results of the first.

All I can suggest is to use shell scripting.  Here's one way:

```
( xdotool search --all --onlyvisible --class 'some_val'
  xdotool search --name 'another val' ) |
    sort | uniq -d
```

Comment: Wow, this is some seriously unintuitive behavior. Thanks for clarifying that.